# How to define a mutually exclusive group of two positional arguments?

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I would like to use `argparse` to make some code to be used in the following two ways:

```
./tester.py all
./tester.py name someprocess
```

i.e. either `all` is specified OR `name` with some additional string.

I have tried to implement as follows:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('all', action='store_true', \
        help = "Stops all processes")
group.add_argument('name', \
        help = "Stops the named process")

print parser.parse_args()
```

which gives me an error

```
ValueError: mutually exclusive arguments must be optional
```

Any idea how to do it right? I also would like to avoid sub parsers in this case.

Comment: Why would you like to avoid sup parsers? This looks exactly like a sub-parser problem!

Comment: They operate already on suparsers. I want to keep it shallow... But if there is no other solution I will try it with subparsers in two levels.

Comment: Change `all` to `--all` and `name` to `--name`.

Comment: @hughdbrown: I know this works, but it is not what I asked.

Answer (score 15):

The question is a year old, but since all the answers suggest a different syntax, I'll give something closer to the OP.

First, the problems with the OP code:

A positional `store_true` does not make sense (even if it is allowed).  It requires no arguments, so it is always `True`.  Giving an 'all' will produce `error: unrecognized arguments: all`.

The other argument takes one value and assigns it to the `name` attribute.  It does not accept an additional `process` value.

Regarding the `mutually_exclusive_group`.  That error message is raised even before `parse_args`.  For such a group to make sense, all the alternatives have to be optional.  That means either having a `--` flag, or be a postional with `nargs` equal to `?` or `*`.  And doesn't make sense to have more than one such positional in the group.

The simplest alternative to using `--all` and `--name`, would be something like this:

```
p=argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('mode', choices=['all','name'])
p.add_argument('process',nargs='?')

def foo(args):
    if args.mode == 'all' and args.process:
        pass # can ignore the  process value or raise a error
    if args.mode == 'name' and args.process is None:
        p.error('name mode requires a process')

args = p.parse_args()
foo(args) # now test the namespace for correct `process` argument.
```

Accepted namespaces would look like:

```
Namespace(mode='name', process='process1')
Namespace(mode='all', process=None)
```

`choices` imitates the behavior of a subparsers argument.  Doing your own tests after `parse_args` is often simpler than making `argparse` do something special.

Comment: +1 simplest indeed, I forgot about `choices`, and I didn't read carefully that OP only needs one process name after `name` argument.

Comment: This is not good enough. The default help gives no indication that `process` is required with `name` and ignored / disallowed with `all`. Eight years later nobody bothered to implement such functionality in argparse. I don't see why mutually exclusive groups couldn't contain positional arguments, as long as there is only a single positional argument in the entire argument parser (as in OP's case and mine).

Comment: @БоратСагдиев, I pointed out that one positional with the right `nargs` (and a default) can be used in such a group.  The OP had the wrong kind of positional.  Formatting the usage line for a fancy set of conditions is not a trivial task.  Write your own, or use the `description/epilog` to explain what you require.

Comment: Indeed, I tried it with an option and a positional argument with `nargs='?'` and it seems to work, for the most part. When I first add the option to the group, and then the positional argument, the help correctly indicates that the two arguments are mutually exclusive. However, when the positional is added first and then the option, it just shows `[-o] [positional]` as if they could be used in conjunction, although actually using them in conjunction causes an error, as expected.

Comment: @БоратСагдиев, I don't remember the details why, but yes, tor correct usage display, the positional should be last of the group.  The usage formatter is not very sophisticated and easily broken.  But during parsing the groups testing is performed by unrelated code.  When I explored implementing a more general nested groups mechanism some years ago, the usage formatting was a much more complicated task than either the input (defining groups) or testing.

Answer (score 1):

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument('-a','--all', action='store_true', \
        help = "Stops all processes")
group.add_argument('-n','--name', \
        help = "Stops the named process")

print parser.parse_args()
```

./tester.py -h

```
usage: zx.py [-h] (-a | -n NAME)

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -a, --all             Stops all processes
  -n NAME, --name NAME  Stops the named process
```

Answer (score 0):

> "OR name with some additional string."

positional argument cannot take additional string

I think the best solution for you is (named test.py):

```py
import argparse
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
meg = p.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
meg.add_argument('-a', '--all', action='store_true', default=None)
meg.add_argument('-n', '--name', nargs='+')
print p.parse_args([])
print p.parse_args(['-a'])
print p.parse_args('--name process'.split())
print p.parse_args('--name process1 process2'.split())
print p.parse_args('--all --name process1'.split())
```

$ python test.py

```
Namespace(all=None, name=None)
Namespace(all=True, name=None)
Namespace(all=None, name=['process'])
Namespace(all=None, name=['process1', 'process2'])
usage: t2.py [-h] [-a | -n NAME [NAME ...]]
t2.py: error: argument -n/--name: not allowed with argument -a/--all
```

Answer (score 0):

I would agree that this looks exactly like a sub-parser problem, and that if you don't want to make it an optional argument by using `--all` and `--name`, one suggestion from me would be just to ignore the `all` and `name` altogether, and use the following semantics:

1. If `tester.py` is called without any arguments, stop all process.
2. If `tester.py` is called with some arguments, stop only those processes.

Which can be done using:

```
import argparse, sys
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('processes', nargs='*')
parsed = parser.parse(sys.argv[1:])
print parsed
```

which will behave as follows:

```
$ python tester.py
Namespace(processes=[])
$ python tester.py proc1
Namespace(processes=['proc1'])
```

Or, if you insist on your own syntax, you can create a custom class. And actually you're not having a "mutually exclusive group" case, since I assume if `all` is specified, you will ignore the rest of the arguments (even when `name` is one of the other arguments), and when `name` is specified, anything else after that will be regarded as processes' name.

```
import argparse
import sys
class AllOrName(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        if len(values)==0:
            raise argparse.ArgumentError(self, 'too few arguments')
        if values[0]=='all':
            setattr(namespace, 'all', True)
        elif values[0]=='name':
            if len(values)==1:
                raise argparse.ArgumentError(self, 'please specify at least one process name')
            setattr(namespace, 'name', values[1:])
        else:
            raise argparse.ArgumentError(self, 'only "all" or "name" should be specified')

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('processes', nargs='*', action=AllOrName)
parsed = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
print parsed
```

with the following behaviour:

```
$ python argparse_test.py name
usage: argparse_test.py [-h] [processes [processes ...]]
argparse_test.py: error: argument processes: please specify at least one process name

$ python argparse_test.py name proc1
Namespace(name=['proc1'], processes=None)

$ python argparse_test.py all
Namespace(all=True, processes=None)

$ python argparse_test.py host
usage: argparse_test.py [-h] [processes [processes ...]]
argparse_test.py: error: argument processes: only "all" or "name" should be specified

$ python argparse_test.py
usage: argparse_test.py [-h] [processes [processes ...]]
argparse_test.py: error: argument processes: too few arguments
```

Answer (score -2):

This is probably what you're looking for:

```
group.add_argument('--all', dest=is_all, action='store_true')
group.add_argument('--name', dest=names, nargs='+')
```

Passing --name will then require at list one value and store them as a list.